# Emulate fake monitor on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

I want to use a old tablet as a 2nd monitor for my PC. Problem is, they require a 2nd fake monitor. I've seen all the old answers suggesting a virtual display adapter or something else you plug into your PC, but I prefer not to buy anything unless needed. Is there any piece of software that could do the same?

Comment: What does the tablet run? Windows 10 actually has a built in feature for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **[Spacedesk app](https://spacedesk.net/)**, i think it will solve your problem (if your current hardware/software permit it, of course).